# Schengen Visa . No response from the Consulate

Tags: schengen, india, application-status, vfs-global

I just got information from the VFS site that the passport has been received.

However there is no email yet from the consulate. Does that mean that my visa application is rejected ?

A bit worried since now its weekend and I can't really collect my passport till Monday :(

Comment: It's post-submission anxiety. Even if you did have an answerable question,  there's nothing to be done other than to brass it out.

Comment: @GayotFow Haha. Well yeah! You are right. Watching a lot of movies